# Glassfish server.log compression and archiving

Tags: logging, compression, glassfish, archive

I'm looking for a simple solution for the following problem.

- We have some glassfish server.log files that are getting quite large (about 700mb per day) for a high traffic web application. We need to retain the logs for an indeterminate (long!) amount of time.
- I need a simple way to archive the logs at the end of each (day? week? etc) into a zip file or something similar.

Can this be done via Glassfish itself? Or do I need to write a batch/powershell script to do it for me, and scheduler it on the server?

Cheers,
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glassfish can manage the number of files to retain in the domain/logs directory but does not manage compression and archival.  I would recommend a shell script (if using a *NIX OS) using gzip to compress and generate your zip file that is scheduled using cron.

Answer (score 0):

You gotta write a script. We have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using **collect-log-files**:

> /path/to/glassfish/asadmin collect-log-files

This command will create a .zip file containing all logs from

> /path/to/glassfish/.../domain/logs/

and as default store it in directory

> /path/to/glassfish/.../domain/collected-logs/